# Is the average of the average, the average?

Tags: probability, variance, average

This question comes from chapter 3 of "Concepts in Thermal Physics" by Blundell & Blundell. The common result for variance is derived as follows:

$$\sigma_x^2 = <(x-<x>)^2>=<(x^2+<x>^2-2x<x>)>=<x^2>+<x>^2-2<x><x>=<x^2>-<x>^2$$

This implies that $<2x<x>>=2<x><x>$, and $<<x>^2>=<x>^2$. Both of these seem to imply that averaging an already averaged value does nothing. Is this true? If so, why?

Comment: Intuitively, once you average you get a single data point, namely the average. The average value that a single data point takes on is that value. So the average of the average is the same as the average

Comment: I found two analogies useful. One way to think of this is that it's a "projection" onto the average since it's a lossy operation that gives you an approximation for the data. Projections are idempotent, ie $P^2=P$ and that works for averages too. Alternatively you can think of it as a smoothing operation that removes variance. Once all the variance is gone and you try to remove it again, it's still gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally $<x>$ is the expectation of $x$, which is $\int x p(x) dx$, where $p(x)$ is the probability density function. But once calculated, $\mu=<x>$ is just a number, so $$<<x>>\equiv<\mu>=\int \mu p(x) dx=\mu \int p(x) dx=\mu.$$ Thus in something like $<x-<x>>$ it should really say $<x-\mu>$ to make it clear that it's a constant.

Comment: Ohhh, yeah, I got tangled up on the fact that $<x>$ is an integral and forgot it ends up as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If $c$ is a constant, then

$$\langle c \rangle = c$$
and
$$\langle c f(x) \rangle = c\  \langle f(x) \rangle$$

for any function of $x$.

And guess what? $\langle x \rangle$ is a constant! I know the notation is incredibly confusing, but that's really all that's going on here.

(And also the square of a constant is also a constant too, if that wasn't clear.)